# MSI Laptop - trouble with NVidia Driver and dual screens

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, games

(UPDATED)

I have a gaming laptop with

- Nvidia GTX 1060 card
- Ubuntu 17.04
- added the graphics-drivers ppa and installed the nvidia-381 driver (latest)
- two monitors: the built in one, and an external one connected with an HDMI cable

This setup shouldn't be rocket science and I'm sure I'm not the only one trying to set up Ubuntu like this... but man, what a f@cking mess!

I could narrow it down:
if I reboot the laptop with the HDMI cable plugged in then something goes wrong and the result is that the screen look stretched... and I couldn't find any other resolution than to purge and reinstall the nvidia drivers. (there must be a simpler way... but I don't know what).
As a workaround I can unplug the HDMI cable, boot with a single (built-in) monitor and then plug it back in once the graphical interface came up. That seems to work.

Does anyone with X.org or NVidia mastery know what the heck is going on?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem with similar configuration (almost the same except it is a Razer Blade). The only workaround that I "found" is:
1) configuring the laptop monitor as primary
2) wait until your laptop fully boots
3) login
4) plug your HDMI
5) configure it your monitor as extended display

Now every-time you want to reset or shutdown you need to unplug your HDMI and then plug it when you have login to your Ubuntu.